# Imacros - Check for duplicate value in a CSV

Tags: javascript, imacros

Firefox - 52.0.1
iMacros - 8.9.7
Windows 10

I would like to know how can I check whether the value is already present in a particular CSV or not.

Suppose I am extracting posts from facebook, I want to make sure that I extract new posts only.
Example code - 
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:POST EXTRACT=TXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your CSV file has the 'fbposts.csv.txt' name and is located in the 'D:\iMacros\Downloads' folder. You can try the following workaround as a certain solution:

```
SET filePosts "fbposts.csv.txt"
SET folderPosts "D:/iMacros/Downloads"
SET urlFbPage https://www.facebook.com/...

SET filePosts EVAL("{{!LOOP}} == 1 ? 'file:///{{folderPosts}}/{{filePosts}}' : 'javascript:undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{filePosts}}
SET extPos EVAL("{{!LOOP}} == 1 ? 1 : 0;")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS={{extPos}} TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET text EVAL("{{!LOOP}} == 1 ? '{{!EXTRACT}}' : '{{text}}';")
SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET urlFbPage EVAL("{{!LOOP}} == 1 ? '{{urlFbPage}}' : 'javascript:undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{urlFbPage}}
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:POST EXTRACT=TXT

SET folderPosts EVAL("var reg = new RegExp('/', 'g'); '{{text}}'.indexOf('{{!EXTRACT}}') > -1 ? '' : '{{folderPosts}}'.replace(reg, '\\\\');")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{folderPosts}} FILE={{filePosts}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

Comment: Looks kool, Could you please explain me, is it effective as i would have 1000 rows data, how much time would it take?

Comment: I basically want to check the if the url of the post is already present in the csv, if it is then macro should hit the like button. Stuff like that

Comment: Well, if you can't figure out how to do that, I would advise to ask a new question and post your codes for extracting urls and liking there.